# Oracle Temporary table Space reasons for excessive use and sizing

Tags: oracle

In Oracle how to find which operations/queries are causing excessive use of Temporary table Space and how to estimate its size?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this query to find whats exactly is filling temp tablespace

```
SELECT a.username, a.SID, a.serial#, a.osuser, b.TABLESPACE, b.blocks,
c.sql_text
FROM v$session a, v$tempseg_usage b, v$sqlarea c
WHERE a.saddr = b.session_addr
AND c.address = a.sql_address
AND c.hash_value = a.sql_hash_value
ORDER BY b.TABLESPACE, b.blocks;
```

Answer (score 2):

Some useful SQL to see temp usage:

1. Show current temp usage by session:

   ```
   select DISTINCT(se.username), se.machine, se.program, se.osuser, to_char(se.LOGON_TIME, 'DD-MON HH:MM') login, se.sid, se.serial#,
   su.blocks/1048576 * (to_number(rtrim(p.value))) as "Chunks (Mb)", tablespace
   from     v$sort_usage su, v$parameter p, v$session se
   where    p.name = 'db_block_size'
   and      su.session_addr = se.saddr
   and su.tablespace = '&TEMP'
   order by se.username, login, se.sid;
   ```
2. Show current total temp usage:

   ```
   select inst_id,round(NVL( sum(s.blocks) * to_number(p.value)/1024/1024, 0)) as "Temp Usage (MB)"
   from gv$sort_usage s, v$parameter p
   where p.name='db_block_size'
   and s.tablespace='&ts'
   group by inst_id,p.value;
   ```
3. Show historical temp usage (change the dates appropriately):

   ```
   select distinct user_id, session_id,session_serial#, sql_id, program, machine 
   from dba_hist_active_sess_history 
   where sample_time between to_date('20161017 1830','yyyymmdd hh24mi') and to_date('20161017 1835','yyyymmdd hh24mi')
   and event = 'direct path write temp';
   ```

If your temporary tablespace is filling up, use query 3 for a time period shortly before and after the tablespace full alert. This will show you the SQLs of all sessions actively writing to TEMP.

Estimating the size needed is more art than science, and depends on what is using the space. Take several samples of the output of Query 2 during peak load events. Think about what might happen if all of your typical temp-using SQLs ran at the same time. And generally play it safe and add more than you think you'll need.

Comment: In order to be allowed to use `dba_hist_active_sess_history` you need to have the enterprise edition and the the additional cost option for the "performance and tuning pack"

Answer (score 0):

The query that I've been using for monitoring temp space usage is:

```
SELECT b.tablespace,
        b.segfile# AS seg_file_num,
        b.segblk# AS seg_block_num,
        b.blocks AS used_blocks,
        b.blocks * p.value AS used_bytes,
        a.sid,
        a.serial# AS serial_num,
        a.username,
        a.osuser,
        a.program,
        a.status,
        cast ( sql.address AS varchar2 ( 50 ) ) AS address_text,
        sql.hash_value,
        sql.sql_id,
        cast ( substr ( sql.sql_fulltext, 1, 4000 ) AS varchar2 ( 4000 char ) ) AS sql_text
    FROM v$session a
    JOIN v$sort_usage b
        ON ( a.saddr = b.session_addr )
    JOIN v$parameter p
        ON ( p.name = 'db_block_size' )
    LEFT JOIN v$sql sql
        ON ( a.sql_address = sql.address
            AND a.sql_hash_value = sql.hash_value ) ;
```

I also poll the database(s) of interest once per minute and stash the results.